# Match 5th and 6th character to select value

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to match the 5th and 6th character in an input field to a value from a select menu.

I'll post some dummy HTML to demonstrate what I mean

```
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="AB"></option>
  <option value="CD"></option>
  <option value="EF"></option>
  <option value="GH"></option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="myInput" />
```

I need to find for example if the input is (1111AB111) then alert(true)... all other characters are not important, I need to match the 5th and 6th character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made  a jsFiddle, showing a rough way of doing it, here: http://jsfiddle.net/TN5Ru/

```
function twoMatchingCharacters(selectElement,inputElement){
    if($(selectElement).val() === $(inputElement).val().slice(4,6)){
      $('p').text('That is a match');                
                  }else{
      $('p').text('That is not a match');
                  }
}

$('.mySelect').change(function(){
    twoMatchingCharacters($('.mySelect'),$('.myInput'));          
});

$('.myInput').keyup(function(){
    twoMatchingCharacters($('.mySelect'),$('.myInput'));         
});
```

Obviously, you won't want to change the text of every paragraph on the page, and there are prettier ways of binding the function, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, this is more akin to what I need

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
var n = str.match(/^.{4}(.{2})/);
```

and then `n[1]` is 5th and 6th character string.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are powerful but can drain performance unnecessarily in cases like yours. What you really need is a simple substring function:

```
if (yourString.substr(4, 2) == theOptionValue) {
    // Do something
}
```

You could also put this in a switch statement, depending on your circumstances. jQuery is a fantastic tool, but one mustn't forget that it is a library and not a language of its own and that a lot can be done with pure old fashioned JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested and working...

```
$(function() {
    $("input.myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text.length < 6) return;
        text = text.substr(4, 2);
        var $option = $("select.mySelect option[value='" + text + "']");
        if ($option.length == 0) return;
        alert("Found " + text);
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/UBhy9/

Comment: Thanks, might be longer winded that others but works fine so 1+

Comment: If people want to -1 then please explain why or no-one will learn anything.  Thanks :)

Comment: Haha - no worries.  It just bugs when I see -1 without reason :)  You can actually trim out a lot of the code.  I code defensively so there's error checking in there.  The only thing it doesn't account for is lowercase entries.

Answer (score 0):

try (tested):

```
$( "input.myInput" ).bind('keyup', function() {
    var fifthandsixth = ($(this).val())[4] + ($(this).val())[5];
    if ( $(".mySelect > option[value='" + fifthandsixth + "']")[0] ) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
        // alert("false");
    }
});
```